# how can set image to fullscreen in swiftUI?

Tags: ios, swiftui

how can set image to fullscreen in swiftUI?

I'd tried to use this method

```
background(Image("aa").frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all))
```

or

```
.background(Image("aa").aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all))
```

it's not show to fullscreen.

this is original image

[image]

But, I always show this....

[image]

where has issues?

Comment: Background to what? Needed minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.scaleToFil()` should the image be larger than the screen.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/scaledtofit()

```
Image("aa")
.resizable()
.scaledToFit()
```

If the image is smaller than the screen, use `.scaledToFil()`

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/scaledtofill()

```
Image("aa")
.resizable()
.scaledToFil()
```

Comment: I'd used this methods, but cannot fullscreen.